Pandas. TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
I've been given a problem to solve which i seem to do great.
The problem is: Print the average amount of reviews among books with a rating above 4 and more than 1000 total ratings, and also show ones with rating in the range of 2-3 and total ratings below 500
Here is my code:
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('data/GoodReads_100k_books.csv')

above = df[(df['rating'] > 4) & (df['totalratings'] > 1000)].mean()

below = df[(2 <= df['rating'] <= 3) & (df['totalratings'] < 500)].mean()

print(above)

print(below)

To me it seems fine but it returns this error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 5
      1 import pandas as pd 
      3 df = pd.read_csv('data/GoodReads_100k_books.csv')
----> 5 above = df[(df['rating'] > 4) & (df['totalratings'] > 1000)].mean()
      7 below = df[(2 <= df['rating'] <= 3) & (df['totalratings'] < 500)].mean()
      9 print(above)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I've asked TabnineAI what is wrong with the code and why does it return this error.
It said that there is nothing wrong with the code and the concatination has nothing to do with my code.
How can i solve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You're trying to take the mean of every column in the dataframe, and presumably there is one which is a mixture of string and integer values; which is giving you that error. For example, try pd.Series(['a', 1, 4]).mean(). You probably just want above = df[(df['rating'] > 4) & (df['totalratings'] > 1000)]['rating'].mean()

The error message is indicating that the mean() function is trying to convert a list of strings to numeric. This is happening because the mean() function is being applied to the entire df, including the 'title' column which contains string values.
To fix this, you should apply the mean() function only to the numeric columns. Here's a shortcut:
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('data/GoodReads_100k_books.csv')

numeric_columns = ['rating', 'totalratings']

above = df[(df['rating'] > 4) & (df['totalratings'] > 1000)][numeric_columns].mean()
below = df[(df['rating'] >= 2) & (df['rating'] <= 3) & (df['totalratings'] < 500)][numeric_columns].mean()
print(above)

print(below)

